# Django use automatic search field filtering from another viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, filtering

I have 2 different viewsets StoreViewSet and ShowcaseViewSet.

In my StoreViewSet, I have:

```
 search_fields = ['name_search', 'address__address1_search', 'address__postcode', 'address__city_search',
                     'address__country']
```

When I GET on my StoreViewSet I can pass search parameter like this:

```
/api/x?search=mysearch
```

And it automatically filter on the search fields, this is great.

Now I made a custom method in ShowcaseViewSet that call:

```
stores = Store.Objects.all()
```

Here I need a way to call the automatic StoreViewSet filtering and pass him the "request" with the search parameter.

This custom method need to remain in the ShowcaseViewSet to maintain a correct rest url.

What can I do here to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is really two questions, so one at a time:

**Filtering**: You can use [`self.filter_queryset`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L140) to filter based on your configuration, the same as in the default [`list()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L37) function for standard model ViewSets.

```
@action(detail=False)
def filter_stuff(self, request):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
    ...
    return Response(data=...)
```

**Sharing**: If you are trying to use another ViewSet's configuration, then you can either copy it in from the other viewset (`OtherViewSet.search_fields`) but you should really create a shared list and use it in both places:

```
_shared_search = ['name_search', ...]

class ViewSet1(...):
    search_fields = _shared_search

class ViewSet2(...):
    search_fields = _shared_search
```

Comment: Ok I see, so i can't really filter an object who isn't the object from the viewset ? 
Thanks for the second answer it really helped me.